# Adding First Name in ABUnknownPerson

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm trying to create a contact that has a first name, last name, phone email and company that is all loaded from text fields on an earlier page.

I got the email and phone properties to load when adding the contact, but i have no idea on how to add the other fields. to be specific, its in the following lines:

```
ABMultiValueRef firstName = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABStringPropertyType);
bool didAdd = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(firstName, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(self.nameLabel.text), kABOtherLabel, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, firstName, &anError);
```

my problem lies within the CFStringRef, I don't know what to use for that value. It crashes when it reaches the last line of code. also didAdd is checked to be true before executing the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();

ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,                    (__bridge CFTypeRef)firstName, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty,                     (__bridge CFTypeRef)lastName, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPrefixProperty,                       (__bridge CFTypeRef)prefix, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonSuffixProperty,                       (__bridge CFTypeRef)suffix, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonNicknameProperty,                     (__bridge CFTypeRef)nickname, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonOrganizationProperty,                 (__bridge CFTypeRef)organization, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonJobTitleProperty,                     (__bridge CFTypeRef)jobTitle, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonDepartmentProperty,                   (__bridge CFTypeRef)department, NULL);
```

firstName, LastName, etc... are NSStrings